# Bundler can't find a gem that I can install using gem install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I am developing two gems side-by-side, one that contains some pure ruby functionality and one with an interface for Rails.

The Rails gem (rwanda-rails) depends on the pure Ruby gem (rwanda) with `spec.add_runtime_dependency "rwanda" "~> 0.6.0"` in the .gemspec.  However, for some reason bundler can't find this new version -- although I can install it with `gem install`:

```
15:40 slack@kevin:~/rails/rwanda-rails[master]$ gem install rwanda
Successfully installed rwanda-0.6.0
Parsing documentation for rwanda-0.6.0
Done installing documentation for rwanda after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
15:48 slack@kevin:~/rails/rwanda-rails[master]$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rwanda~> 0.6.0":
  In Gemfile:
    rwanda-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rwanda~> 0.6.0 (>= 0) ruby
Could not find gem 'rwanda~> 0.6.0 (>= 0) ruby', which is required by gem 'rwanda-rails (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.
```

Confirm that `rwanda` is installed:

```
15:50 slack@kevin:~/rails/rwanda-rails[master]$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

[...]
rwanda (0.6.0)
```

Bundler is configured to install gems in `~/vendor/bundle/`:

```
15:50 slack@kevin:~/rails/rwanda-rails[master]$ ls -1 ~/vendor/bundle/gems/
[...lots of gems...]
rwanda-0.4.0
rwanda-0.5.3
rwanda-0.6.0
```

I guess I'm confused about where bundler is installing its gems and why it can't find a gem that seems to be available.

I'm using ruby 2.2.1, set via a .ruby-version in the gem's directory.  $GEM_PATH and $GEM_HOME are not set (should they be?  does rbenv take care of that?).

I also installed and then removed rbenv-bundler (after finding the warnings from the rbenv developers) and am worried that it might have left something behind that is interfering?

I have three plugins installed for rbenv: binstubs, gem-rehash and ruby-build.

I've also tried `rbenv rehash`, `bundle install --binstubs` and `bundle update` (which fails with the same message as `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you are missing a `,` between the gem name and the version in the gemspec:

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency("rwanda", "~> 0.6.0")
```